# Maven shade plugin relocate file to main folder

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-shade-plugin

I am using maven-shade-plugin version 3.2.1 to include/exclude some classes. I am trying to relocate files inside a folder to main folder in a jar.

```
<configuration>
        <filters>
                ...
        </filters>
        <relocations>
                <relocation>
                        <pattern>org/example</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org/example/example2</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
        </relocations>
</configuration>
```

If I use it as above, it moves files under `org.example` to `org.example.example2` (just to make sure it is working). If I use just "/", then it creates folder and subfolder with empty names and places files under them. And nothing happens if i keep `</shadedPattern>` empty.

I want to place files in the main directory but i am not able to do it so far.

Is there any way to achieve this through shade plugin or with something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you should use `./` for the shaded pattern like below:

```
<configuration>
    <filters>
            ...
    </filters>
    <relocations>
            <relocation>
                    <pattern>org/example</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>./</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
    </relocations>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It creates 3 folder/subfolders with empty names. (example.jar\\\\shadedfiles). Just to be more clear, when i use ./test, it moves files to example.jar\\\test\shadedfiles

Comment: It is strange but sounds like an environmental issue because it is working in my mac  os. What is your os? windows?

Comment: yes, windows. using maven package build through intellij

Comment: I can not replicate windows environment right now but may be you can try \ or .\ This is directory separator for windows which is different then linux and mac os

Comment: I tried \\ and .\\ but no luck. And weirdly ${file.separator} gives IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing error which should be resolved as \\

Comment: Then it can be a bug which occurs only in windows :(